# Amazon EC2 - Automatic Restore Snapshot

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm looking to setup a demo environment in Amazon that consists of a pre-configured EC2 image that resets itself back to a snapshot configuration every hour, this is would be a Linux VM.

What would be the best way to go about doing this in EC2? Does Amazon offer any tools for scheduling and reverting to the snapshot or would this need to be done from a third party VM or software?

Comment: 'Reverting to a snapshot' - what do you mean by that? Like in VmWare?

Comment: Yes exactly that type of functionality. I know I have a good, working Snapshot, and I want to roll back to that every hour.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no VMWare-like 'snapshot' functionality in Amazon EC2** (where you can roll-back to a point-in-time).

The network-attached disk storage system used with Amazon EC2 is called Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS). While EBS *does* have a 'snapshot' function, this actually takes a backup of an EBS Volume and stores it in Amazon S3. The snapshot can then be used to **create a new EBS volume**, which will contain the same contents as the original disk at the time the snapshot was created.

One option would be to **launch a *new* Amazon EC2 instance**, which will automatically create a new boot disk from the indicated Amazon Machine Image (AMI). This is the way to launch new machines with the same disk content. However, this might not lend itself well to your "revert every half hour" since it requires a new machine to be started, which will also trigger a new hourly billing cycle.

You might be able to **script** the deletion of files or the reload of some database tables, but this will depend upon your particular system and applications.